# When using webview, some of my sites open in chome rather than directly in the app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app for android with Android Studio, for our forums.
We are using a webview in our program so that we can show a website we have made (http://henryslifeisajokeapp.tk) in the application.

All runs fine, until the user tries to click the signup or login buttons then the app automatically opens the site in Chrome or a default web browser.

However upon signing into the browser, the app itself isnt signed in, only the browser is.

Help would be appreciated. I am using android studio 3.4.1

Im running the program on my phone, it runs fine, the site is accessible but cannot perform the actions I have listed above.

```html
package com.example.forums6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.loadUrl("http://henryslifeisajokeapp.tk");



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the links within the webview you must set a `WebViewClient` for the webview

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Heres the code for the custom WebViewClient

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
  }
}
```

Add the above class to your MainActivity.java file

If you want you can control the links the webview opens. To find more information please have a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#HandlingNavigation)